# C# & Unity: Change displayed Time with good performance on mobile Device

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, mobile

Hey guys so I made this function which is called every frame.
- You think this is a good way to save performance or is there a better way?

```
    private void GetCurrentTime()
{
    m_TimeNow = System.Convert.ToString(System.DateTime.Now);

    //If the previous time is not equals to the current time (without seconds = every minute)
    if (m_PreTime != m_TimeNow.Remove(14))
    {                                                   //Change the Time displayed on the screen:
        m_PreTime = m_TimeNow.Remove(14);               //1. Copy current Time
        m_Times = m_TimeNow.Split(' ');                 //2. Split to following parts
        m_Time = m_Times[1].Remove(4);                  //3. Cutout seconds

        m_Text_Time.text = m_Time + " " + m_Times[2];   //4. And change UI-Text: Time + AM/PM
    }
}
```

This function is called every Frame and will be on a mobile android device.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may see some improvements in your implementation. Here is what I can tell you from my own experience.

## For a short answer, this his how I would write your function:

```
// 
// Version 2
// 
class TimerExample_V2 {
    private DateTime    _TimeNow = System.DateTime.Now;
    private DateTime    _PreTime = System.DateTime.Now;
    private string      _format = "t";
    private string      _cultureName = "en-US";

    public TimerExample_V2() {
        CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo(_cultureName);
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
    }

    public void UpdateCurrentTimeUI() {
        _TimeNow = System.DateTime.Now;

        if(_PreTime.Minute != _TimeNow.Minute) {
            // Note: this case appear only once per minute.
            _PreTime = System.DateTime.Now;
            string newText = _TimeNow.ToString(_format);
            //m_Text_Time.text = newText; // Update unity display
            // I omit this display unity. (Same cost in both case)
        }
    }
```

## Now for a longer answer with explanations:

- Strings (Performance):
  Strings are generally costly, specially when dealing with str processing and comparisons. For instance 'String.Remove(int)' creates a new string, which may call several costly methods such as malloc etc (Behind the scene). As far as I see, you keep all your dates as strings but could use only the raw format DateTime. A better approach would be to keep your data in the 'DateTime' format and convert them as a string only for the end user. (For instance, to update your Unity display). It is better to compare two int (ex: DateTime.ElapsedMilliseconds) than string (ex: m_PreTime != m_TimeNow.Remove(14))
- Date format (Flexibility):
  You would have several issues when dealing with different date formats. Your implementation expects "HH:mm AM / PM" format, but user may have a possibility to change the format (24h for instance).. Use the dark magic power that C# gives you. For instance, use the CultureInfo or the already implemented "DateTime.ToString(format)". (I just learned about 'CultureInfo'. There may be other ways. But as a general rule, see whether the language  already has the feature you need).
- Functions name:
  This is a little thing, but try to have little functions that does what it says. In your case, from 'GetCurrentTime', we would expect a return value. This function actually update a display and return void. Something like 'UpdateTimeDisplay' is probably better.
- Duplicate calls:
  A second little thing: you have 2 calls to m_timeNow.Remove(14). You could create a new string once (From this function) and use this new string in both places.

## Experiment (Measurements and validation)

Anyway, when dealing with performance, you have to measure, benchmark your code. (As an example, I first did an implementation for your GetCurrentTime and realized it wasn't actually better.). The following is a little experiemnt I created to show you some measurement. I'm not a C# shaman expert, nor a performance wizard expert but I hope my example is clear enought. I run the experiment on my laptop: (Intel i5-3320M CPU @ 2.60GHz).

I have two implementations of your function. I run 10 000 times each function and print the execution time for each. (I omit the call to update the unity display, which is the same in both cases). My measurements show that your implementation took 45 ms, the other took 23 ms.

The second implementation sounds better. However, don't forget that I called 10 000 times the functions. In practice, with 60fps, you call the update 60 times per seconds. On my laptop, 60 iterations took 0 miliseconds for both.

There is another element to point out:

```
m_PreTime   = m_TimeNow.Remove(14);
m_Times     = m_TimeNow.Split(' ');
m_Time      = m_Times[1].Remove(4);
```

These are kind of slow functions since dealing with strings creation. However, there are called only once per minute. As a matter of fack, I measured that, my implementation, when switching minute, uses the same amount of milliseconds as your. I may have failed my measurement or whatever, but maybe, once each minute, my function takes as much time as your. In all other cases, it is 'faster'. I may summerize this point using a quote:

> "Solve for the most common case first, Not for the most generic"

(As far as I remember, this is a quote from the talk about optimization: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXaxk27zwlk. Good talk btw)

## Experiment (Source code)

So here is the full code of my terrible experiment:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Diagnostics;

// Instructions to compile (With mono)
// csc Program.cs
// mono Program.exe

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        TimerExample_V1 timer_v1 = new TimerExample_V1();
        TimerExample_V2 timer_v2 = new TimerExample_V2();

        Stopwatch profiler;
        int nbBenchLoops = 10000; // 10 000 times
        float t1;
        float t2;

        // Profil version 1
        profiler = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for(int k = 0; k < nbBenchLoops; ++k) {
            timer_v1.UpdateCurrentTimeUI();
        }
        t1 = profiler.ElapsedMilliseconds;


        // Profil version 2
        profiler = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for(int k = 0; k < nbBenchLoops; ++k) {
            timer_v2.UpdateCurrentTimeUI();
        }
        t2 = profiler.ElapsedMilliseconds;


        // Print mesured times
        Console.WriteLine("[SCOPE_PROFILER] [Version 1]: {0} ms", t1);
        Console.WriteLine("[SCOPE_PROFILER] [Version 2]: {0} ms", t2);
    }
}

//
// Version 1
//
class TimerExample_V1 {
    private string      m_TimeNow = System.Convert.ToString(System.DateTime.Now);
    private string      m_PreTime = System.Convert.ToString(System.DateTime.Now);
    private string[]    m_Times;
    private string      m_Time;

    public void UpdateCurrentTimeUI() {
        m_TimeNow = System.Convert.ToString(System.DateTime.Now);

        if (m_PreTime != m_TimeNow.Remove(14)) {
            // Note: this case appear only once per minute.
            m_PreTime   = m_TimeNow.Remove(14);
            m_Times     = m_TimeNow.Split(' ');
            m_Time      = m_Times[1].Remove(4);

            string newText = m_Time + " " + m_Times[2];
            //m_Text_Time.text = newText; // Update unity display
            // I omit this display unity. (Same cost in both case)
        }

    }
}


// 
// Version 2
// 
class TimerExample_V2 {
    private DateTime    _TimeNow = System.DateTime.Now;
    private DateTime    _PreTime = System.DateTime.Now;
    private string      _format = "t";
    private string      _cultureName = "en-US";

    public TimerExample_V2() {
        CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo(_cultureName);
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
    }

    public void UpdateCurrentTimeUI() {
        _TimeNow = System.DateTime.Now;

        if(_PreTime.Minute != _TimeNow.Minute) {
            // Note: this case appear only once per minute.
            _PreTime = System.DateTime.Now;
            string newText = _TimeNow.ToString(_format);
            //m_Text_Time.text = newText; // Update unity display
            // I omit this display unity. (Same cost in both case)
        }
    }
}
```

For further information about DateTime.ToString and CultureInfo, checkout the documentation:

- [CultureInfo C# Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [DateTime.ToString C# Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx)

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Althogh I'm late, I want to thank you for your nice answer. This explained more than I needed. Keep going :)